# How to choose class in Vue.js depending on multiple values?

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to choose class of an element bases on `importance`:

```
   <strong> Importance: 
       <span :class="importance ? (calculate class here)">
        </span>  {{someText}}
    </strong>
```

Let's say the class vlue should be `imp0` ,`imp1`,`imp2`, `imp3` or  `imp4`, depending on whether `importance` equals 0,1,2,3 or 4.

You may ask why not calculate the value in a method function?

The answer is: to keep the class value synced with the result of a separate method which also gets `importance` as input parameter after the class is rendered.

So wondering how can I achieve this?

Update: I managed to do it with a convulted ternary conditional:

```
 :class="importance==0 ? 'imp0': (importance==1? 'imp1': (importance==2 ? 'imp2': (importance==3 ? 'imp3': 'imp4')))
```

but wondering if there is a more clean way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mapping is that direct, you can let it go with simple expression:

```
:class="'imp' + importance"
```

... but I strongly advise you to at least consider it a technical debt. Remember, you can use any attribute in your CSS selector, not just classes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What do you mean by 'technical debt' though?

Comment: The same as [everybody else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt), I suppose. ) While this solution is simple, it's apparently neither readable nor flexible. What exactly are the differences between those 'imp1', 'imp2', etc. classes?

Comment: Well, those classes show different icons, which help the form to be more readable. I tried first to use SVG icons, but found that even more cumbersome.